# Big-O notation 1/O(n) = Omega(n)

Tags: big-o

I have received the assignment to prove `1/O(n) = Ω(n)`

However, this would mean that `n` element of `O(n) => 1/n` element of `Ω(n)` which is clearly wrong.

So my question is: Is the statement `1/O(n) = Ω(n)` correct?

EDIT: I send an Email to the assistant who wrote the questions. And used the example of `f(n) = 1`.
He then said, that the statement is indeed incorrect.

Comment: “this would mean that n element of O(n) => 1/n element of Omega(n)” – no, it doesn’t. The equals sign in the big-O notation isn’t really an equals sign at all and it doesn’t follow the normal rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation *1/O(n) = Ω(n)* is a bit vague. There is really no *O(n)* on it's own, there is only *f(n) ~ O(n)*, which is a statement about values of function *f* (there is a constant *C* so that *f(n) < Cn* for each *n*).

And the statement to prove, if I understand it correctly, is "if function *f(n)* is *O(n)* than *1/f(n)* is *Ω(n)*", formally:

*f(n) ~ O(n) => 1/f(n) ~ Ω(n)*

**Edit:** Except I don't think I understand it correctly, because *f(n) = 1 ~ O(n)*, but *1/f(n) = f(n) = 1* is clearly isn't *Ω(n)*. Weren't the assignment *f(n) ~ O(n) => 1/f(n) ~ Ω(1/n)* instead?

**Edit:** Different people tend to use different operators. Most common is *f(n) = O(n)*, but that is confusing because the right hand side is not a function, so it can't be normal equality. We usually used *f(n) ~ O(n)* in school, which is less confusing, but still inconsistent with common use of that operator for general equivalence relations. Most consistent operator would be *f(n) ∈ O(n)*, because the right hand side can reasonably be treated as set of functions.

Comment: The assignment is:
"Prove formally that: 1/O(n) = Omega(n)"
It's written on a paper right before me, so it's not something I heard/looked up wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

O(n) more or less implies the following, for some polynomial function f(x), some polynomial function g(x) and O(f(x)):
In terms of magnitude, we have |f(x)| <= M|g(x)|, for some M. Basically, *f is bounded above by a constant times g*.

Ω(n) implies that, for some polynomial h(x), some polynomial k(x) and Ω(h(x)):
In terms of magnitude, |h(x)| >= M|k(x)|, for some M. Basically, *h is bounded below by a constant times k*.

So, for (O(f(x)))^-1, 1/|f(x)| <= 1/(M|g(x)|).
A bit of re-arranging gives M|g(x)| <= |f(x)| - i.e. f(x) is bounded below by a constant times g, which is *exactly the same* as our definition for Ω(n) above.

It's a tad scratchy to be a formal proof, but it should get you started.

Comment: So you think the *1/O(n)* means *1/f(n) ~ O(1/n)* (and indeed than *1/O(n) ⇔ Ω(n)*)? Because what that means is the real question here­­—the *O(n)* is a set, so there's no universal definition of what *1/O(n)* should mean.

Comment: I agree. O(n) refers to the set, but, given the question, this was more or less the best I could do. Assuming the question was written in all seriousness - which I have to assume is the case, then the above proof should hold. Whilst O(n) refers to a bounded set, because it refers to a bounded set of _polynomials_, an inverse like the one above *should* be possible